# Why this application is well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $C$ be a curve. An application $\phi:C\to \mathbb P^n$ is called
>   regular in a point $P\in C$ if there are regular functions
>   $f_0,\ldots,f_n$ defined in a neighborhood $V$ of $P$ in $C$ such that
>
> $$\phi(x)=[f_0:\ldots:f_n]$$
>
> And there is some $f_i$, such that $f_i(P)\neq 0$.

My question is why this application is well-defined.

More specifically:

1.Why $x_1=x_2\implies \phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2)$?

2.Why if $f_i(P)\neq 0$, then there is some neighborhood of $P$ which $f_i$ is not zero?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. This is injectivity, which we don't want (to assume). $\phi$ is a map by assumption.
2. Well, $D(f_i) = \{Q : f_i(Q) \neq 0\}$ is such a neighborhood.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused myself, I meant $x_1= x_2\implies \phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2)$

Comment: Why this set is open?

Comment: Because $f_i$ is a regular function. You should recall the definitions of a regular function, an (affine) variety, the Zariski topology etc.